# Async method always return true while unit testing Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, async-await, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am writing unit test case for one of the angular component but I am not getting the unit test passed.
I have a method which calculate the minutes and return true or false based on the logic.

```
  async isLesserthanExpirationTime(creationTime: string) {
    var currentTime = new Date(new Date().toISOString());
    var minutes = (new Date(currentTime).valueOf() - new Date(creationTime).valueOf()) / 60000;
    if (minutes > 20)
      return false;

return true;
```

}

Here is another method depends on that which makes a decesion based on above method.

```
async getDetailsForId(id: string) {
    if (await this.isLesserthanExpirationTime(createdTime))
      let response = await this.DLService.getById(id).toPromise();
      //something
    else
      let response = await this.VDLService.getById(id).toPromise();
      //something
      }
```

I am unable to get the UT right for this, the islesserthanexpirationtime method always return true. I have tried without mocking also, tried passing the value to the createdTime, and while debugging the method returns false as expected but post that I dont know whats happening, it just executes the if loop instead of else loop.

Here is my UT

```
it('should has ids', async() => {
    spyOn(VDLService, 'getById');
    spyOn(component, 'isLesserthanExpirationTime').and.returnValue(false);
    component.getDetailsForId(Id);
    expect(component.isLesserthanExpirationTime).toBeFalsy();
    expect(VDLService.getById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried `spyOn(component, 'isLesserthanExpirationTime').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(false));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing `async` about `isLesserthanExpirationTime`, change it to:

```
 isLesserthanExpirationTime(creationTime: string) {
    var currentTime = new Date(new Date().toISOString());
    var minutes = (new Date(currentTime).valueOf() - new Date(creationTime).valueOf()) / 60000;
    if (minutes > 20)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Change the function to:

```
async getDetailsForId(id: string) {
    if (this.isLesserthanExpirationTime(createdTime))
      let response = await this.DLService.getById(id).toPromise();
      //something
    else
      let response = await this.VDLService.getById(id).toPromise();
      //something
      }
```

And the unit test:

```
it('should has ids', async(done) => { // add done here so we can call it when it is done
    spyOn(VDLService, 'getById').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('hello world')); // up to you what you want to resolve it to
    spyOn(component, 'isLesserthanExpirationTime').and.returnValue(false);
    await component.getDetailsForId(1); // make sure this promise resolves
    expect(component.isLesserthanExpirationTime).toBeFalsy();
    expect(VDLService.getById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    done();
  });
```